# Remotely connect Windows Server 2012 core VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, remote-access

I have a cloned image (VM) of Windows Server 2012 core (cloned from a golden image at some datacenter); I want to remotely connect to this cloned VM through my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Could anyone guide me how to get started? What all I would require?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get the whole VM thing, but if you mean you want to connect to Windows using the Remote Desktop Protocol, you can use Remmina which I believe is pre-installed on Ubuntu.

Good luck